# Strong params: How to process nested json code?

Tags: ruby, json, api, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm trying to write an update method that processes JSON. The JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "organization": {
    "id": 1,
    "nodes": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Hello",
        "description": "My description."
      },
      {
        "id": 101,
        "title": "fdhgh",
        "description": "My description."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My update method is as follows:

```
  def update
    organization = Organization.find(params[:id])
    nodes = params[:organization][:nodes]
    nodes.each do |node|
      n = Node.find(node[:id])
      unless n.update_attributes(node_params)
        render json: organization, status: :failed
      end
    end
    render json: diagram, status: :ok
  end

  private
    def node_params
      params.require(:organization).permit(nodes: [:title, :description])
    end
```

Unfortunately, `n.update_attributes(node_params)` generates:

```
Unpermitted parameter: id
Unpermitted parameter: id
Unpermitted parameter: id
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
*** ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError Exception: unknown attribute 'nodes' for Node.
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong and to write this update method?

Comment: the update method from which you are trying to update nodes is in Organisations Controller right?

Comment: Yes, it is in the Organizations Controller.

Comment: Then you can use nested attribute for nodes so that all the nodes with same organisation will get saved and updated

Comment: Thanks Amit, the solution in the answer below also worked. Or would `nested_attribute` have some sort of advantage over the solution below?

Comment: You don't need to loop trough `nodes params` if you use `nested_attribute`

Comment: Thanks, I've asked a follow-up question on how to set this up, here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34828645

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `unless n.update_attributes(node_params)` line, you're trying to update Node `n` with `nodes_params`, which are all of the nodes from your JSON minus the ids:

`{"nodes"=>[{"title"=>"Hello", "description"=>"My description."}, {"title"=>"fdhgh", "description"=>"My description."}]}`

You could just add `:id` as a permitted node parameter, cut out the `nodes` assignment step, iterate over `node_params` instead, and just omit the `:id` when updating Node `n`.  E.g.,

```
def update
  organization = Organization.find(params[:id])
  node_params.each do |node|
    n = Node.find(node[:id])
    unless n.update_attributes(node.except(:id))
      render json: organization, status: :failed
    end
  end
  render json: diagram, status: :ok
end

private
  def node_params
    params.require(:organization).permit(nodes: [:id, :title, :description])
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it. `n = Node.find(node[:id])` fails with `TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer)`. Using `debugger` on that line, `node` returns: `["nodes", [{"id"=>1, "title"=>"title", "description"=>"Desc."}, {"id"=>101, "title"=>"fdhgh", "description"=>"Hi."}]]`. So it still seems to be an array. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: So, `node_params` and `node` return the same output, except that `node_params` has it all (i.e. 2 nodes) between `{...}` while `node` has it all between `[...]` (but still 2 nodes, so not `each`).

Comment: Yes! If I change that line to `node_params[:nodes].each do |node|` than it works. Is this whole setup still a secure/safe way of updating?

Comment: @Nick, seems you missed am important detail - you need to specify an organization's id as a permitted param (the first line of the update method looks for it) `organization = Organization.find(params[:id])`; so, the permit construction should take the following form:
`params.require(:organization).permit(:id, {nodes: [:id, :title, :description]})`

Comment: @DreamWalker, thanks. I tried it without `....permit(:id, ...` and placed `debugger` at the beginning of the `update` method. Then `params[:id]` is available and it finds the right `organization`. So it seems that I don't need to add that to the params. Does that make sense? Or is there a security problem?

Comment: @Nick, I guess it extracts the organization id from the route itself, if you curious you may step with debugger into this proc and check this.