# How to use nested_attributes when processing JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, serialization, nested-attributes

I'm trying to write an update method that processes JSON. The JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "organization": {
    "id": 1,
    "nodes": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Hello",
        "description": "My description."
      },
      {
        "id": 101,
        "title": "fdhgh",
        "description": "My description."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Organization model:

```
has_many :nodes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :nodes, reject_if: :new_record?
```

Organization serializer:

```
attributes :id
has_many :nodes
```

Node serializer:

```
attributes :id, :title, :description
```

Update method in the organizations controller:

```
def update
  organization = Organization.find(params[:id])
  if organization.update_attributes(nodes_attributes: node_params.except(:id))
    render json: organization, status: :ok
  else
    render json: organization, status: :failed
  end
end

private
  def node_params
    params.require(:organization).permit(nodes: [:id, :title, :description])
  end
```

I also tried adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to the organization *serializer*, but that does not seem to be correct as it generated an error (`undefined method 'accepts_nested_attributes_for'`), so I've only added `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to the model and not to the serializer.

The code above generates the error below, referring to the `update_attributes` line in the update method. What am I doing wrong?

> no implicit conversion of String into Integer

In debugger `node_params` returns:

```
Unpermitted parameters: id
{"nodes"=>[{"id"=>101, "title"=>"gsdgdsfgsdg.", "description"=>"dgdsfgd."}, {"id"=>1, "title"=>"ertret.", "description"=>"etewtete."}]}
```

---

**Update:** Got it to work using the following:

```
def update
  organization = Organization.find(params[:id])
  if organization.update_attributes(nodes_params)
    render json: organization, status: :ok
  else
    render json: organization, status: :failed
  end
end

private
  def node_params
    params.require(:organization).permit(:id, nodes_attributes: [:id, :title, :description])
  end
```

To the serializer I added `root: :nodes_attributes`.

It now all works, but **I'm concerned about including the id in `node_params`. Is that safe?** Wouldn't it now be possible to edit the id of the `organization` and `node` (which shouldn't be allowed)? **Would the following be a proper solution to not allowing it to update the id's:**

```
if organization.update_attributes(nodes_params.except(:id, nodes_attributes: [:id]))
```

Comment: I think you need to remove nodes from params.  You can't set nodes this way with update_attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks super close.

Your json child object 'nodes' need to be 'nodes_attributes'.

```
{
  "organization": {
    "id": 1,
    "nodes_attributes": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Hello",
        "description": "My description."
      },
      {
        "id": 101,
        "title": "fdhgh",
        "description": "My description."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can change that... Shoudn't I write the update model to fit the JSON code? The serializer (in addition to the attributes) just has: `has_many :nodes` and generates the JSON as displayed. I seem to be only able to include `accepts_nested_attributes_for :nodes` in the Organization model and not in the Organization serializer (then it generates an error: `undefined method 'accepts_nested_attributes_for'`).

Comment: I was able to change it to `nodes_attributes` using `root` in the serializer. Now it works (see update in the OP). But I'm concerned about including the id in `node_params`. Is that safe? Wouldn't it now be possible to edit the id of the `organization` and `node` (which shouldn't be allowed)?

Comment: Hey hey.  You will have to add security.  Best is to add a reject_if clause to enforce ownership of nodes by the organization passing in.  If the id is blank it creates a new one.  If it is present it updates the one with that id.  The _destroy of truthy destroys it.   Recommend reading through the api dock to get full details.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Reject_if proc should be added to the accepts nested attributes call in Organization model

Comment: Are you sure this is needed? I just tried and manipulated the id of a node. Upon the patch request it responded with: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` `Couldn't find Node with ID=2 for Organization with ID=1`.  P.S. I already had included `reject_if: :new_record?` so that it only accepts updating existing nodes and doesn't create new ones (which is what I need here).

Comment: Makes sense.   If it is scoping them correctly then you don't have to go further.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this sort of thing.  Put this in your controller.

```
before_action do
  if params[:organization]
    params[:organization][:nodes_attributes] ||= params[:organization].delete :nodes
  end
end
```

It will set the correct attribute in params and still use all the accepts_nested_attributes features.

Comment: Thanks, shouldn't I then also make changes to the `updates_attributes` line and/or to `def node_params`?

Comment: Thanks, I added the result to the original post with the new code to make sure I'm doing as you asked. I get the error message: `Node(#70152224207320) expected, got ActionController::Parameters(#27264600)`.

Comment: I added `debugger` inside `def set_update_params`. Here `params[:nodes_attributes] ||= params.delete :nodes` returns nil, so something there does not seem to work.

Comment: It will be nested.  Updating my answer.  You'll need to tweak appropriately if the organization param is nil.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working now (see added update to the OP).